# Insert mutliple records from a single record in the table using for loop in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, package

In a table, I have a data which I mentioned below.

```
Driver_Name_1 Age   Driver_Name_2 Age   Driver_Name_3 Age
Tony          35    Mark          32
```

From the above one record, I have to insert into the another table with separate row for each driver using for loop.  I have to check the first if Driver Name 1 is not null and then I have to insert the record with Driver Name 1 and age. And If Driver Name 2 is not null then I have to insert another record and go on.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`unpivot`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) clause with [`exclude nulls`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#CHDIBEFI) (which is the default) to perform an insert with plain SQL.

> ```
> insert into t
> select
>   name, age
> from s
> unpivot exclude nulls (
>   (name, age) for grp in (
>     (driver_name_1, age1) as 1,
>     (driver_name_2, age2) as 2,
>     (driver_name_3, age3) as 3
>   )
> )
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from t
> ```
>
> ```
> DRIVER_NAME | AGE
> :---------- | --:
> Tony        |  35
> Mark        |  32
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=336f9f315d3582d2ac0ea3c3c107196e)*

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward & simple, as you described:

```
begin
  for cur_r in (select * from your_table) loop
    if cur_r.driver_name_1 is not null then
       insert into another_table (name, age) values (cur_r.driver_name_1, driver_age_1);
    end if;

    if cur_r.driver_name_2 is not null then
       insert into another_table (name, age) values (cur_r.driver_name_2, driver_age_2);
    end if;

    if cur_r.driver_name_3 is not null then
       insert into another_table (name, age) values (cur_r.driver_name_3, driver_age_3);
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
```